# apache cxf interceptor attributes

Tags: cxf, jax-rs, interceptor

I have the following interceptor

```
public class MyInterceptorextends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>{
  public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
     message.put("myatt", "value");
  }
}
```

And I'm creating a JAXWS Client proxy

```
    CalculatorService proxy = JAXRSClientFactory.create("http://eisoukr.victoria-insbg.com/API", CalculatorService.class, providers);
    ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(proxy);
    config.getInInterceptors().add(new MyInterceptor());
```

How can I read the "myatt" attribute from the proxy or is there another way to exchange attributes between the proxy and the interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

There is a ClientConfiguration has a getResponseContext() method on it that can be used to retrieve the various properties set on the message.

Comment: I've tried to put an attribute with
        message.put("myatt", "Xxx");
but config.getResponseContext() returned empty map :(...